# Error while downloading MNIST data

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist

I am trying to download MNIST train and test set. I download file from website and the save it in folder named samples.After extracting I get a file named as train_images. But in function call I get error that name train is not defined.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import gzip
import os
import urllib
import numpy
SOURCE_URL = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'


def maybe_download(filename, work_directory):

    if not os.path.exists(work_directory):
        os.mkdir(work_directory)
    filepath = os.path.join(work_directory, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        filepath, _ = urllib.urlretrieve(SOURCE_URL + filename, filepath)
        statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
        print('Succesfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
    print(filepath)
    return filepath
#function call
maybe_download(train-images,"./samples")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your function call. First parameter you use (train-images) is not defined in your code.

Tested version of your code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from urllib import request

SOURCE_URL = 'http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'


def maybe_download(filename, work_directory):

    if not os.path.exists(work_directory):
        os.mkdir(work_directory)
    filepath = os.path.join(work_directory, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        filepath, _ = request.urlretrieve(SOURCE_URL + filename, filepath)
        statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
        print('Succesfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
    print(filepath)
    return filepath

#function call
maybe_download("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz","./samples")

exit(0)
```

1. In your case python tries to interpret *train-image* as variable
   name. In case you want use it as file name you should wrap it with quotes.
2. Please notice if you use python3 as you specified in tags then fix `urlencode` imports before usage.
3. Also you can check http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-image with your browser. It returns 404 as `train-image` does not exists. But there are several zipped archives with training sets. You can check correct URLs via browser: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist.

You can try to use some IDE (like: [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) for your development. It highlights some kind of mentioned problems.

Comment: train image is the file name that I get after extracting the training set from MNIST site. I'm a newbie.

Comment: @user10163680 if you want to use train-image as file name try to wrap it with quotes. Otherwise python tries to parse it as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `train-images` instead of `train_images` in your function call. Variable names can't contain dashes – `train-images` is parsed as `train - images`.

Comment: I tried again but its not working.I want to download MNIST data and read it.